# Multidimensional array from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

From JSON object below

```
{cols:[{"id":"t","label":"Title","type":"string"},{"id":"l","label":"Avg ","type":"string"},{"id":"lb","label":"High","type":"string"},{"id":"lo","label":"Low","type":"string"}],rows:[{"c":[{"v":"Change navigation"},{"v":5.6666666666667},{"v":"10"},{"v":"1"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Executive leadership"},{"v":6.0666666666667},{"v":"7"},{"v":"3"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Business ownership"},{"v":5.8095238095238},{"v":"10"},{"v":"2"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Change enablement"},{"v":6.4285714285714},{"v":"9"},{"v":"5"}]}]}
```

how can i get something like

```
[['Change navigation',6.5333333333333],['Executive leadership',6.0666666666667],['Business ownership',5.8095238095238],['Change enablement',6.4285714285714]]
```

somebody posted the code for one dimensional array from this.cant figure out multidimensional in javascript

```
var arr = [],
i = 0;
for (; i < json.rows.length; i++) {
arr.push(json.rows[i].c[0].v + '=' + json.rows[i].c[1].v);
```

}

which gives

```
['Change navigation=6.5333333333333','Executive leadership=6.0666666666667', 'Business ownership=5.8095238095238','Change enablement=6.4285714285714']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of pushing a concatenated string, push an entire array to your existing array:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0, l = json.rows.length; i < l; i++) {
    arr.push([ json.rows[i].c[0].v, json.rows[i].c[1].v ]);
}
```