# Multidimensional array gotten from values in JSON file in JavaScript, using Object.keys

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

Based on the question https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/323738/como-incluir-arquivo-json-dentro-de-um-js (in Portuguese), but he does not have an array and I have an array. I applied that and the variables were undefined due to a lack of an array that he did not.

You can test using to run the preview.

I also tried to apply the questions:

1. [get size of json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756104/get-size-of-json-object/6756305)
2. [Multidimensional array from JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072387/multidimensional-array-from-json-object)

   - Firstly in the HTML file:

```html
  <p id="name">Name 1</p>
  <p id="age">Age 1</p>
  <p id="name">Name 2</p>
  <p id="age">Age 2</p>
  <p id="name">Name 3</p>
  <p id="age">Age 3</p>
  <p id="name">Name 4</p>
  <p id="age">Age 4</p>
  <p id="name">Name 5</p>
  <p id="age">Age 5</p>
```

- JSON:

```
{
  "people": 
  [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Person Name 0",
      "age": 15
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Person Name 1",
      "age": 25
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Person Name 2",
      "age": 35
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Person Name 3",
      "age": 45
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Person Name 4",
      "age": 55
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Person Name 5",
      "age": 60
    }
  ]
}
```

- Based on that question in Portuguese like:

```js
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
          callback(rawFile.responseText);
      }
  }
  rawFile.send(null);
}

readTextFile("../json/people.json", function(text)
{
  var people = JSON.parse(text);

  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  name.innerHTML = people.name;

  var age = document.getElementById('age');
  age.innerHTML = people.age;

  console.log(people);


});
```

- Or using `Object.keys`, like:

```js
readTextFile("../json/people.json", function(text){
  var people = JSON.parse(text);

  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  name.innerHTML = Object.keys(people.name).length;

  var age = document.getElementById('age');
  age.innerHTML = Object.keys(people.age).length;

  console.log(people);


});
```

```js
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
          callback(rawFile.responseText);
      }
  }
  rawFile.send(null);
}

readTextFile("https://pastebin.com/raw/CzxURs8y", function(text)
{
  var people = JSON.parse(text);

  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  name.innerHTML = people.name;

  var age = document.getElementById('age');
  age.innerHTML = people.age;

  console.log(people);


});
```

```html
  <p id="name">Name 1</p>
  <p id="age">Age 1</p>
  <p id="name">Name 2</p>
  <p id="age">Age 2</p>
  <p id="name">Name 3</p>
  <p id="age">Age 3</p>
  <p id="name">Name 4</p>
  <p id="age">Age 4</p>
  <p id="name">Name 5</p>
  <p id="age">Age 5</p>
```

Comment: Element ID should always be unique.

Comment: Although browsers will do something with duplicate id values, results are unpredictable. This needs fixing as the first step.

Comment: @JayB and @traktor53, the problem is that my teacher requires to keep `people`, I can not change the JSON.

Comment: your json is an object where a key named `people` contains your array you need to access it accordingly, eg `data =JSON.parse(text); data.people[0].name`

Comment: @GustavoReis the html element id always needs to be unique (change the html, not the json)

Comment: Different Element IDs require multiple variables. It is a waste of codes. I know that I would use `Array.from.foreach`, but it does not support `document.ElementById` and `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fetch("../json/people.json")
    .then(r=>r.json())
    .then(json=>{
        const nameElms = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[id='name']"));
        const ageElms = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[id='age']"));
        nameElms.forEach((n,i)=>{
            const person = json.people[i];
            n.textContent = person.name;
        })
        ageElms.forEach((n,i)=>{
            const person = json.people[i];
            n.textContent = person.age;
        })
    })
```

Comment: Are you sure that it supports inner.HTML?

Comment: it almost supports innerHTML, but it does not support. Too bad. In HTML, `<div id="image"></div>`, and in JavaScript: ``imageElms.forEach((n, i) => 
  {
    const product = json.products[i];
    let images =`<img src="https:${product.image}" />`;
    n.textContent.innerHTML =+ images;
  })``.

Comment: `n.innerHTML = images`